# Saving variable in a cookie - console.log returns the variable with session id

Tags: javascript, cookies

Here's an example JS:

```
document.cookie= "This is a cookie";
```

When I use console.log, this is what the console shows: This is a cookie; PHPSESSID=erosfseqvbb7j52qfurs89fvn1

Why is this happening and how can I retrieve only "This is a cookie"?

Comment: Take a look here to see how `document.cookie` works https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting and setting document.cookie don't work in quite the same way.
As [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie) explains:

`var x = document.cookie;` returns all cookies separated by commas

`document.cookie = "x=1";` sets a single cookie value (in this case cookie x to value 1)

It also give an example for reading a specific cookie:

```
document.cookie = "test1=Hello";
document.cookie = "test2=World";

var myCookie = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)test2\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");

alert(myCookie);
```

Comment: Thank you, I modified the code for my needs and it seems to be working nice. One more question -  I'd like to use cookies on a site with file upload and save the path to an image in a cookie, so everytime I upload a file the cookie should be overwritten. How can I remove a specific cookie (let's say test1) to be able to set it to another value?

Comment: Sorry, I got it working. I forgot to remove an example line where I set test1 to something else and it kept alerting it instead of the thing I wanted. Big thanks!

Comment: Ok, one more thing - this code doesn't seem to be saving anything to myCookie: `document.cookie = '"imagePath=' + data + '"';`  . What is wrong with it?

Comment: you dont need the double quotes. Just `document.cookie = 'imagePath=' + data;`